# Array.prototype.some not working with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ternary

Why do the following two snippets not return the same value?

```
[1,2,3,4].some((el) => {
    if (el === 4) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

--> returns true

```
[1,2,3,4].some((el) => {
    el === 4 ? true : false;
});
```

--> returns false

Comment: missing return statement with function with curly brackets

Comment: what is so bad with `.some(el => el === 4)`

Comment: Your expression can be reduced to `[1,2,3,4].some(element => element === 4);`

Comment: thanks y'all, totally thought the return is implied in the ternary and would be valid as a return for the arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You are missing `return`.

```js
var x=[1,2,3,4].some((el) => {
     return el === 4 ? true : false;
});
console.log(x);
//Or you can do this
var y=[1,2,3,4].some(el => el === 4);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no return in the second version, so it's returning undefined.

What you need is:

```
[1,2,3,4].some((el) => {
    return el === 4 ? true : false;
});
```

...or you need to take away the braces:

```
[1,2,3,4].some(el => el === 4 ? true : false);
```